# UIImageViews embed in UIScrollView in code w/ auto layout on

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout, viewdidload

I am currently having trouble with my iOS app and Autolayout. I want to let the user scroll photos from Tumblr in a `UIScrollView` (similar to Photos app, when scrolling your library). So when my ImageViewController gets on screen, it has an array of posts but no data for the images yet. My problem is the following :

In my scrollView, I want to add as many UIImageViewS as needed, and I would like them to be all the same size. How should I do it? I tried many (probably bad designed :-/) ways, like `initwithframe:` with auto layout on and keeping a reference to them in a `NSMutableArray`...

My goal now is to add them to my scrollView in `viewDidLoad` and have correct constraints set.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my poor English

**EDIT**

OK I solved my problem: I used a nice scrollView and set its constraints with auto layout in `viewWillAppear`

Here is the code for those interested (sorry for layout) : 
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self downloadPhotos];
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.selectedImageIndex * self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0) animated:NO];

// Add UIImageViewS to self.scrollView with constraints and so on...
NSMutableDictionary *viewsDictionnary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableString *imageViewsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count; i++) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.scrollView.bounds];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder_imageView"];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    [imageViews addObject:imageView];
    [viewsDictionnary setObject:imageView forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageView%d", i]];
    [imageViewsString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[imageView%d]", i]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
}
self.imageViews = imageViews;
NSString *horizontal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|%@|", imageViewsString];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:horizontal options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDictionnary]];
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.selectedImageIndex * self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0) animated:NO];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad 
 {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      float posX = 0.0 , poxY = 0.0;

      float sizeWidth = 100 , sizeHeight = 200;

      float scrollContentWidth = 320.0;

      scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=YES;
      scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
      scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
      self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = TRUE;

      for(int i=0;i<[imageArray count];i++)
      {
           NSString *imageURL = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];

           UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(posX,posY,sizeWidth,sizeHeight)];

           [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageURL]];

           [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

           [imageView addConstraint:
           [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView 
           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
           toItem:imageView 
           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
           multiplier:1
           constant:100]];

           [imageView  addConstraint:
           [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView 
           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
           toItem:imageView 
           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
           multiplier:1
           constant:200]];

           [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480.0,scrollContentWidth)];

           scrollContentWidth=scrollContentWidth+320.0;

           posX = posX + 320.0;
      }
 }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. As I said, I wanted to have it working with auto layout because the scrollView's size will change often. So I guess that it's somewhat forbidden to use setFrame for the UIImageView... (or initWithFrame as well). Secondly, I should have said that the images will get loaded in another thread. So I just want to have a pointer (stored in my property imageViews) to them, so that I can set their image later. Thanks for your reply anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using a scrollView but using a collectionView instead (iOS 6 and above).  You will probably insist that you need to use iOS 5 or iOS 4.  Make things easy for yourself,  collectionViews make memory management easy and if you plan on loading a lot of photos in view, just go with collection views.  You can then create a collectionViewCell which will have a UIImageView.  The UIImageView will be only one size, you can then set its image scaling propery to scale to fit so no matter what shape or size, the images will fit in the image view and not be distorted.  Do some research on colletion views, heck, there probably is a tutorial you can use to load images from the internet and display them using a collection view.

Comment: This would be a good idea, but I would also like to zoom in the images, to have a toolbar under it and a custom view displaying the caption from tumblr. Thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: You can do all of that with a collectionView.  A collectionView is a scrollView with a lot more functionality added to it.  I really suggest at least checking out a tutorial.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. I already use two collectionViews in my app. The thing is that I want to use full scrolling abilities here and not a collectionView. Therefore, I am asking to stay with a scrollView and use some constraint. But thanks for your help. I keep experimenting the hard way with UIScrollView.